# SQL - Inconsistent datetime conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am hoping someone can give me an explanation the the following issue involving converting a varchar to datetime.

The code below works:

```
SELECT
    mt.matter_code,
    ud.uds_type,
    ud.group_no,
    ud.ud_field##2,
    convert(datetime,ud.ud_field##2,103) hearingDate
FROM dbo.matdb mt
    INNER JOIN dbo.matdb_add_in ad
            ON mt.mt_int_code  = ad.mt_int_code
            AND ad.add_in_code = 'OUTAA'
    INNER JOIN dbo.uddetail ud
            ON convert(varchar,ad.mt_add_in_int_code) = ud.owner_code
            AND ud.parent_code = ad.add_in_code
            AND ud.po_type_char = 'A'
            AND ud.uds_type = 'LPR'
            --AND ud.uds_type IN (SELECT s FROM dbo.split(',','LPR'))
WHERE mt.mt_type   = 'MATA'
AND mt.matter_code = '118-1'
ORDER BY ud.ud_field##2 ASC;
```

However if we substitute the

```
'AND ud.uds_type = 'LPR'
```

FOR

```
'AND ud.uds_type IN (SELECT s FROM dbo.split(',','LPR'))'
```

I get the following conversion error message:
'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.'

Both lines of code return the EXACT same results when not using a conversion. However as soon as the conversion is introduced when using dbo.split() I get the error message mentioned above.

Am I missing some kind of reference or is this a bug of sorts?

EDIT:
dbo.split function

```
USE [Vfile_Dev]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Split]    Script Date: 02/18/2016 13:28:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

EDIT: If anyone is interested, I have provided a solution below which was made possible thanks to Ivan. Additional checks were made on ud.ud_field##2 to ensure that there were no blanks and the dbo.split results are now inserted into a table variable.

```
INSERT INTO @screenTable
SELECT s FROM dbo.split(',','LPR,COU');

SELECT
    mt.matter_code,
    ud.uds_type,
    ud.group_no,
    isnull(nullif(ud.ud_field##2,''),'01/01/1990') as hdNorm,
    convert(datetime, isnull(nullif(ud.ud_field##2,''),'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000')) AS hdConverted
FROM dbo.matdb mt
    INNER JOIN dbo.matdb_add_in ad
            ON mt.mt_int_code  = ad.mt_int_code
            AND ad.add_in_code = 'OUTAA'
    INNER JOIN dbo.uddetail ud
            ON convert(varchar, ad.mt_add_in_int_code) = ud.owner_code
            AND ud.parent_code = ad.add_in_code
            AND ud.uds_type IN (select * from @screenTable)
WHERE mt.mt_type   = 'MATA'
AND mt.matter_code = '118-1'
ORDER BY group_no ASC;
```

Comment: How about if you share your split function?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have invalid data in the table that doesn't match your search criteria? Depending on the case you might be reading + converting also those rows to be discarded later, but then the error happens.

Comment: Check your source table for inconsistent values.

Comment: And, I guess, `dbo.split` is nondeterministic.

Comment: @IvanStarostin - ud_field##2 will always contain data that can convert to datetime. And yes.

Comment: Review actual execution plan. It must be completely different (comparing between constant and function). I don't believe that making such a function _inline_ improves performance. I'recommend to 1) hide all it's internals (TF) and make it deterministic (looks like `schemabinding` will be enough) 2) finally rewrite it on CLR via regexp since there is no relational work

Comment: Change to `CASE WHEN ISDATE(ud.ud_field##2) THEN CONVERT(datetime, ud.ud_field##2,103) END AS hearingDate` and check when it is null

Comment: When it's inline it complicates overall execution plan of outer query and makes this job much harder for optimizer to find efficient plan. When there are joins to some tables inside IF - yes, combining with outer query may produce better plan. But this function does not refer any data tables.

Comment: Did you actually validate data stored in ud_field##2 column? I mean all rows even those which don't fit query conditions.

Comment: Some are blank; I've added some checks to ensure that they are converted. Unfortunately I am limited to what I can change with the function as it's used by many other processes. I took the approach of making it 'deterministic' by inserting the function results into a variable. This seems to work a treat. I have added the working code to my original post. Let me know if you have any further thoughts on this. @IvanStarostin

Comment: Modify `select *` in subquery to use specific column, think of way to avoid conversion in the join predicate (int<-->varchar). Since the conversion exists - define exact varchar size (e.g. `varchar(10)`; preferrably - to match `ud.owner_code` size). And review actual execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ud.ud_field##2` contains more than just `datetime` data. `ud.uds_type` and one of the reasons you need the `convert(datetime,ud.ud_field##2,103)`. When you use a WHERE clause directly, the predicate is applied *before* the `CONVERT` function is called. This means SQL Server is only converting data that can be converted. When you use your `split` function, SQL Server is no longer able to do that.

If `ud.ud_field##2` is being used to store multiple datatypes, then you have a design problem. There are a few different solutions (e.g. create multiple `uddetail` tables - one for each datatype, add columns to `uddetail` - one for each datatype, etc.).

Here's my example:

```
CREATE TABLE #DifferentData1
  (
     [DataType]           VARCHAR(20),-- This is our code for the type of data we have in Sometimes_datetime
     [Sometimes_datetime] VARCHAR(20)-- This is datetime or something else
  )

CREATE TABLE #DifferentData2
  (
     [DataType]        VARCHAR(20),-- This is our code for the type of data we have
     [Always_datetime] DATETIME,-- This is ALWAYS datetime
     [Other_data]      VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #DifferentData1
            ([DataType],
             [Sometimes_datetime])
VALUES      ( 'LPR',CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)),
            ( 'Almost LPR',CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)),
            ('Not LPR','Some other data type')

INSERT INTO #DifferentData2
            ([DataType],
             [Always_datetime],
             [Other_data])
VALUES      ( 'LPR',CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 103),NULL),
            ( 'Almost LPR',NULL,CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)),
            ('Not LPR',NULL,'Some other data type')

-- Let's see what we have
SELECT [DataType],
       [Sometimes_datetime]
FROM   #DifferentData1

SELECT [DataType],
       [Always_datetime],
       [Other_data]
FROM   #DifferentData2
```

Now, we can filter with a simple WHERE clause and everything is fine for either table:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Sometimes_datetime], 103)
FROM   #DifferentData1
WHERE  [DataType] = 'LPR'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Always_datetime], 103)
FROM   #DifferentData2
WHERE  [DataType] = 'LPR'
```

This works for `#DifferentData1` because the predicate (WHERE clause) is applied *before* the `CONVERT`. However, when using the `split` function, SQL Sever is attempting to `CONVERT` *after* the predicate is applied. This causes it to fail. `#DifferentData2` will still work as intended:

```
-- This fails
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Sometimes_datetime], 103)
FROM   #DifferentData1
WHERE  [DataType] IN
       (SELECT [SplitData]
        FROM   [dbo].[SplitString]('LPR', ','))
OPTION (MERGE JOIN) 

-- This works!
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Always_datetime], 103)
FROM   #DifferentData2
WHERE  [DataType] IN
       (SELECT [SplitData]
        FROM   [dbo].[SplitString]('LPR', ','))
OPTION (MERGE JOIN)
```

Note: I had to force a MERGE JOIN, because the predicate *might* be applied before the `CONVERT` if a LOOP JOIN is used. If your data set is small, it may work to simply force a LOOP JOIN, but this is NOT recommended as a general solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Sometimes_datetime], 103)
FROM   #DifferentData1
WHERE  [DataType] IN
       (SELECT [SplitData]
        FROM   [dbo].[SplitString]('LPR', ','))
OPTION (LOOP JOIN)
```

Comment: To confirm - ud.ud_field##2 will always contain a valid date format for conversion to datetime. dbo.split is only used to separate a comma delimited and store it in a table. I have edited my post to include the dbo.split function.